# Difference between speed of sound into a star

Tags: acoustics, plasma-physics, stars

I try to understand the following graphics with x-axis being the radius of a typical star :

[image: speed of sound inside a star]

I would like to knwo if $\delta c/c$ represents the relative error between theorical and experimental values or if it represents the fluctuations of speed of sound inside. If these are fluctuations, one could get the mean speed all over radii or standard deviation.

I am not sure what it is exactly.

Any help is welcome

Comment: What is the source of your graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$c$ here is the measured sound speed. $\delta c$ is the difference between the measured sound speed (from astero/helio-seismology) and the sound speed predicted by a theoretical model of the star/Sun.

The speed of sound varies by much more than 1% in the interior of a star!

Comment: .So the main discrepancy in current models is in the zone 0.4 - 0.65 R/R0 (with R0 the radius of sun): can anyone could explain what's the origin of this issue ?

at R = 0.4 - 0.65 R0, are we in radiative or convective zone ?
Regards

Comment: @youpilat13 Probably a different question. The plots show it is related to the assumed composition. The discrepancy is just below the transition from radiation to convection. This region is affected by radiative diffusion and perhaps other "non-standard" mixing processes.

Comment: could you indicate me please what's roughly the radius value of frontier between radiative and convective zone for a standard star like the sun ? thanks

Comment: @youpilat13 Where the dotted line is.

Comment: ok, about $0.7 R_{sun}$, is it a common value for stars like sun ? thanks

Comment: @youpilat13 For stars "like the Sun" it is exactly the same. It would be smaller for lower mass main sequence stars and larger for higher mass main sequence stars. It would be smaller for higher metallicity stars at a given mass and vice-versa.